# Karma - TypeScript - Can't find variable: exports

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, karma-mocha

I am learning to write Unit Test cases for an angular project written in `Typescript`. I have chosen `Karma` and `Mocha` for that. Here is the application structure:

```
Project/
├── app/
│   └── components/
│       └── mycoolcomponent/
│           ├── coolcomp.spec.ts
│           └── coolcomp.ts
│   
├── node_modules/
│
├── gulpfile.js
│── karma.conf.js
│── package.json 
└── tsconfig.json
```

Here is the **karma.conf.js**:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({        
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],

        files: [
            'app/components/mycoolcomponent/coolcomp.ts',
            'app/components/mycoolcomponent/coolcomp.spec.ts'
        ],

        exclude: [
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            '**/*.ts': ['typescript']
        },

        typescriptPreprocessor: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true, // generate source maps
                noResolve: false // enforce type resolution
            },
            transformPath: function (path) {
                return path.replace(/\.ts$/, '.js');
            }
        },       

        reporters: ['progress'],        
        port: 9876,        
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,        
        browsers: ['Chrome', 'IE', 'PhantomJS'],
        singleRun: true,
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "Scripts/app",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "inlineSources": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "typings/boot",
    "typings/boot.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**Gulp task**:

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    new Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});
```

**Package.json** has the following dev-dependencies:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/expect": "^1.20.1",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.41",
    "@types/sinon": "^2.3.3",
    "chai": "^4.1.0",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "gridstack": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.4.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.1.7",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
    "karma-typescript-preprocessor": "^0.3.1",
    "merge": "1.2.0",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "sinon": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "typings": "2.1.0"
  }
```

**coolcomp.ts** :

```
export class Calculator {
    add(x: number, y: number): number {
        return x + y;
    }        
}
```

**coolcomp.spec.ts** :

```
import { Calculator } from "./coolcomp";    
var expect = chai.expect;

describe("Calculator Mocha", () => {
    var calculator;
    beforeEach(() => {
        calculator = new Calculator();
    });

    xit("can add", () => {
        var result = calculator.add(5, 5);
        expect(result).to.be.equal(1);    
    });
});
```

When I run the gulp task I am getting this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports

However if I remove the `export` keyword from **coolcomp.ts** and the 1st line (import..) from **coolcomp.spec.ts** the tests run smoothly. There are already few questions like this posted here on SO but none helped me.
Can someone please guide me where I am doing it wrong?

**UPDATE**: With the help from StackOverflow community and few other forums I have figured out the solution to this problem. For those who wish to see it here is the url of my code's repository: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/saurabhranjansingh/UnitTestingKarmaMocha)

Comment: Remove moduleResolution. Also try adding the property "types":["mocha", "etc"] in the tsconfig.json

Comment: @LeonardoVenoso I tried it. Didnt work :(

Comment: I have the same config as yours. This is also what I have in the configs: files: [
            { pattern: "file.ts", included: true, watched: false },
            { pattern: "file2.ts", included: true, watched: false }
        ],

Also the plugis: [ require("karma-typescript-preprocessor"), ...]

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: Hi @LeonardoVenoso Can you please post your solution (files) on github where I or others can reference it. Thanks!

Comment: please bro, give me a +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it goes your solution. Remove sinon for a while.

npm uninstall @types/sinon
npm uninstall sinon

Test if tsc works from the command line.
Then execute: "karma start" from the command line. No need gulp.

```
    // Karma configuration
    module.exports = function (config) {
        config.set({
            basePath: "",
            frameworks: [ "karma-typescript" , "mocha", "chai" ],
            files: [
                { pattern: "app/components/mycoolcomponent/**/*.ts", included: true, watches: false  }
            ],
            preprocessors: { "app/components/mycoolcomponent/**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"] },
            port: 8081,
            typescriptPreprocessor: {
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    noResolve: false
                },
                transformPath: function(path) {
                    return path.replace(/\.ts$/, ".js");
                }
            },
            browsers: [ "Chrome" ],
            reporters: [ "progress", "mocha", "karma-typescript" ],
            autoWatch: true,
            singleRun: false,
            concurrency: Infinity,
            plugins: [
                require("karma-typescript"),
                require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
                require("karma-sourcemap-writer"),
                require("karma-mocha-reporter"),
                require("karma-mocha"),
                require("karma-chai")
            ]
        })
    }
```

// TSCONFIG

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true
},
"types": [
  "node",
  "mocha",
  "chai",
  "expect"
],
"version": "2.4.1",
"include": [
    "app/**/*.ts"
]
```

}

// PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "unittestingwithkarmamocha",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/expect": "^1.20.1",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.41",
    "chai": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
    "karma-source-map-support": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-sourcemap-writer": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-typescript": "^3.0.4",
    "karma-typescript-preprocessor": "^0.3.1",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.17",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also please share your tsconfig.json & package.json

Comment: I have made all the changes that you have suggested. Unfortunately I cant make it work. Can you please have a look at my code on GitHub. I have added the link in the question above. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sure, send this, at night I'll have a look : )

Comment: My code is on Github. I have put the link to it under my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Luftwaffe Ok, noted.

Comment: It works ! Thank you :) I am still exploring why Sinon is throwing the error- TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'. If you know the reason or solution to that please post it here.

Comment: You might need to install some extra libs.

Comment: Yes. I did that now. Added ///<reference path="../../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"/> at the beginning of coolcomp.ts and it worked :)

Comment: @Luftwaffe add this as global. Should not be needed to reference in that way. Anyways it works, good job!!!